# Trouble with CAAnimation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, core-animation

// header file for the card class

```
#import "OWCardView.h"

@implementation OWCardView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.layer.contents      = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"].CGImage;
        self.layer.shadowColor   = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
    }
    return self;
}


- (void) moveCard:(float)xPoint along:(float)yPoint
{
    CGRect someRect = CGRectMake(xPoint, yPoint, 72, 96);

    [UIView animateWithDuration: 3.5
                          delay: 0.3
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations: ^{ self.frame = someRect;}
                     completion: ^(BOOL finished) { }];
}


@end


// part of the Implementation in the view controller's viewDidLoad

[...]
     CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(20.0f, 20.0f, 72.0f, 96.0f);

     // myCard is a property of the viewController
     self.myCard = [[OWCardView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
     [self.view addSubview:self.myCard];
     [self.myCard moveCard: 240 along: 355];     // First call
     [self.myCard moveCard: 50 along: 355];      // Second call
     [self.myCard moveCard: 50 along: 50];       // Third call
[...]
```

Problem: 
Only the last message to moveCard in the viewController is executed; the first and second calls do not execute. What is wrong with the code?

When I comment the third message to moveCard out, the second call is executed and the first does not. If I comment the second and third calls out, then the first call executes. But I want all three animations to occur on the card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have is that the animation is asynchronous.

The code does not wait for each animation to finish before executing the next one. So it blasts through the first two calls and starts the third animation immediately and cancels out the first two meaning that you'll only see the last animation.

You have to use the completed block to do something after the animation has finished.

The easy way to do this is like so...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 3.5
                      delay: 0.3
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations: ^{ self.frame = CGRectMake(240, 355, 72, 96);}
                 completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 3.5
                          delay: 0.3
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations: ^{ self.frame = CGRectMake(50, 355, 72, 96);}
                     completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration: 3.5
                              delay: 0.3
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations: ^{ self.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 72, 96);}
                         completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
            //All finished
        }];
    }];
}];
```

You could put this into some sort of recursive function but it's probably just easier to do this.

The other alternative is to use key frame animation where you literally build up the path and timing step by step and then say "GO" and it will do the animation you have built up.

This is probably easier for now though and I've used this kind of thing before.

Answer (score 2):

When you animate a view, any previous animation you applied to the view is immediately cancelled, even if either animation has a non-zero delay.  So if you want to apply sequential animations, you have to add the second animation after the first has ended.  You can use the completion block to detect when the first animation ends.

It's pretty easy to make `moveCard:along:` maintain a queue of target rectangles and apply the animations sequentially:

```
@implementation OWCardView {
    NSMutableArray *pendingRects;
    BOOL isAnimating;
}

- (void)moveCard:(float)xPoint along:(float)yPoint {
    CGRect someRect = CGRectMake(xPoint, yPoint, 72, 96);
    if (!pendingRects) {
        pendingRects = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    [pendingRects addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:someRect]];
    [self startAnimatingIfNeeded];
}

- (void)startAnimatingIfNeeded {
    if (isAnimating)
        return;
    if (pendingRects.count == 0)
        return;
    CGRect rect = [[pendingRects objectAtIndex:0] CGRectValue];
    [pendingRects removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    isAnimating = YES;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.5 delay:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        self.frame = rect;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        isAnimating = NO;
        [self startAnimatingIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the third animation override the fisrt and the second one

you can use this

> ```
> - (void) moveCard:(CGPoint)Point1 point2:(CGPoint)Point2 point3:(CGPoint)Point3
> {
>     CGRect someRect = CGRectMake(Point2.x, Point2.y, 72, 96);
>
>     [UIView animateWithDuration: 3.5
>                           delay: 0.3
>                         options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
>                      animations: ^{ self.frame = someRect;}
>                      completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
>                          someRect = CGRectMake(Point2.x, Point2.y, 72, 96);
>                          [UIView animateWithDuration: 3.5
>                                                delay: 0.3
>                                              options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
>                                           animations: ^{ self.frame = someRect;}
>                                           completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
>
>                                               someRect = CGRectMake(Point3.x, Point3.y, 72, 96);
>                                               [UIView animateWithDuration: 3.5
>                                                                     delay: 0.3
>                                                                   options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
>                                                                animations: ^{ self.frame = someRect;}
>                                                                completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
>
>
>
>                                                                }];
>
>                                           }];
>
>                      }];
> }
> ```

Comment: This won't work. The points you are using are not correct. Besides, if the animation is always the same (which it looks like it is) then you are overcomplicating the whole process.

Comment: maybe you have the right, this method overcomplicating the process, but i work in this case. any way thx for your valuable commet